# Javascript function not being called when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying out this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html and I am testing it on this sandbox here: http://www.problemio.com

When I press the submit button of the form to add a problem, it doesn't do anything, and even there is no output to my javascript console in Chrome.

I also added an alert statement in the JavaScript to see if it is being called, but that also isn't working.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function()
{
    $(".submit").click(function()
    {
    alert ("1");
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&gender=' + gender;

if(name=='' || username=='' || password=='' || gender=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "join.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

and the form setup:

```
<form  name="form"  method="post">
```

Comment: please put the code written by you. no one can imagine the code without seeing it

Comment: Good point, just added the code

Comment: can you post the full html of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `action` attribute on your `form` tag to tell the form where to submit to.

EDIT

Also, the jQuery is not firing because this selector doesn't match your submit button: `$(".submit").click`.  Try `$("input[type=submit]").click`

Comment: How should it look like if I am submitting to the javascript?

Comment: the action is irrelevant, he is doing th submit thru ajax

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the source code sample you indicated, first you must add an `action` attribute (even a fake one containing "#") to the form to enable form submission.

Second, remember the ajax method url must be complete (e.g.: `http://localhost/join.php`).

Edit:
I also prepared a new example based on the one you posted; it is working for me. Please take care of changing the ajax method destination url.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(function() {
            $(".submit").click(function() {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var username = $("#username").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                var gender = $("#gender").val();
                var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&gender=' + gender;

                if(name=='' || username=='' || password=='' || gender=='')
                {
                    $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/test/join.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(){
                            $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                            $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="form" action="#">
        <ul><li>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
        </li><li>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
        </li><li>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
        </li><li>
        <select id="gender" name="gender"> 
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
        </select>
        </li></ul>
        <div >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
        <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
        <span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
        </div></form>
    </body>
</html>
```